# sfdx trying to retrieve code from sandbox - getting 'no results found'

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm looking to deploy my code using sfdx, these are the steps I'm going to take:

Retrieve code from sandbox:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m MetadataType:ClassName,MetadataType:ClassName_Test -u YourSandboxOrgAlias
```

Deploy code to production:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m MetadataType:ClassName,MetadataType:ClassName_Test -l RunAllTests -r ClassName_Test -u YourProdOrgAlias
```

So I tried typing in the first command and pressed enter:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m MetadataType:OnSiteActivityControllerTest.cls,MetadataType:OnSiteActivityController.cls -u Staging
```

but got 'No results found'.

[image]

Please advise.

Also, can you please review the steps above and let me know if they are syntactically correct?

Comment: Note in the 2nd code block, the `-l RunAllTests` will run all tests, and you don't need to specify the `-r ClassName_Test`.  If you only want to run specific tests, used `-l RunSpecifiedTests`

Comment: Thanks @BrianMiller, how can I run only the local tests? same as choosing 'Default' when deploying a change set

Comment: nevermind found the answer, i should be RunLocalTests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the below command:-

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m MetadataType:OnSiteActivityControllerTest.cls,MetadataType:OnSiteActivityController.cls -u Staging
```

you have not defined the **metadata type** name. If you are retriving the apex class, the metadata name would be **ApexClass**, so the correct command would be:-

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass:OnSiteActivityControllerTest,ApexClass:OnSiteActivityController -u Staging
```

Also, **.cls** extension is not required while retrieving.

Reference:- [source:retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm)

Comment: Sweet, thank you!